# Can't get stars to show in simple review system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently trying to implement a simple star review system to my application and I got it working for the most part. But the issue Is I can't get the the review stars to show for the average review of a store. Anyone mind helping me understand what is broken?

**stores/show.html.erb:**

```
<div class="star-rating" data-score= <%= @avg_review %> ></div>
<em><%= "#{@reviews.length} reviews" %></em>
```

This is included at the bottom of the view:

```
<script>
$('.star-rating').raty({
  path: '/assets/',
  readOnly: true,
  score: function() {
        return $(this).attr('data-score');
}
});
</script>
```

**stores_controller.rb:**

```
def show
@reviews = Review.where(store_id: @store.id).order("created_at DESC")

if @review.blank?
  @avg_review = 0
else
  @avg_review = @reviews.average(:rating).round(2)
end
end
```

Thank you a head of time.

Comment: How does the generated data attribute in the HTML look like?

Comment: I think this is what you're asking for `<div class="star-rating" data-score="0"></div>`

Comment: Did you double check that your average query actually returns non zero values for the given store I’d?

Comment: Yes I have did that. It works on individual reviews just not on the average review.

Comment: $(this).attr('data-score') returns string.  If your score function should return an integer, you should use $(this).data('score');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put in your model store:

```
def average_rating
    reviews.count == 0 ? 0 : reviews.average(:rating).round(2)
end
```

(If no star = 0, otherwise we average the notes)

In your view:

```
<span id="average_rating"></span>
```

With the script:

```
<script>
$('#average_rating').raty({
    path: '/assets',
    readOnly: true,
    score: <%= @store.average_rating %>
});
</script>
```